# Invert colours of a PDF with Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

This question has been asked several times on StackExchange but I could not find a solution that really works. Is there a (desirably) pure ghostscript way to invert the colours of a PDF? The command

```
gs \
 -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
 -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
 -dNOPAUSE \
 -dBATCH \
 input.pdf
```

turns input.pdf into a grayscale output.pdf. Is there a similar command that inverts the colours?

Comment: I do not think that this belongs to the TeX subsite, as this is not directly related. There are some questions on the other sites which already provide solutions for it, like using  `-c "{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub} setcolortransfer"` (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/449724/is-it-possible-to-invert-text-and-background-colors-in-a-pdf-when-printing) for example).

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work

Comment: I just verified that it works with an up-to-date GPL Ghostscript 9.52 on Windows (with a PDF file having only text) - "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Nevertheless I think that this question does not belong to this subsite and should rather be asked on Stackoverflow or something like Super User.

Comment: Ok, let me be more specific. It doesn't work in the sense that nothing happens to the PDF. It looks exactly the same. I'm running Ghostscript 9.23 on macOS. I suspect that this is the issue mentioned in the original post, i.e., the solution only works on certain PDF viewers. I disagree that this is the wrong place to ask. Many users here are very knowledgeable about Ghostscript.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems.